# WxBitmap, cannot see correctly image

Tags: c++, image, wxwidgets

I'm trying read a bitmap image and use class wxBitmap with this constructor:

```
wxBitmap (const char bits[], int width, int height, int depth=1)
```

But i cannot understand why when I call the method:

```
wxDC::DrawBitmap (const wxBitmap &bitmap, wxCoord x, wxCoord y, bool useMask=false)
```

the image is completely distorted.

Here's the code:

```
wxBitmap*
MyFrame::readImage(const char* filename, int x, int y)
{
    char* bits = new char[x*y];
    char byte;
    long i = 0;


    std::ifstream f(filename, std::ios::binary);
    f.seekg(54, std::ios::beg);    // skip header

    while(i < x*y)  {
        f.read((char *)&byte, sizeof(char));
        bits[i++] = byte;
    }

    f.close();

    return (new wxBitmap(bits, x, y) );
}
```

After that when I try to draw the bitmap nothing works.

Comment: what is the file format you are reading? Is it in RGB format?  If it is a standard image format (JPG,PNG,GIF,etc...) you should use the built in wxWidgets methods for reading images or look at the wxBitmap::LoadFile method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of poking inside a bitmap file and creating a `wxBitmap` out of the raw data, use `wxImage` to load the file, then convert it to a `wxBitmap`:

```
wxBitmap*
MyFrame::readImage(const char* filename)
{
    wxImage image(wxString(filename));
    return new wxBitmap(image);
}
```

Comment: Image is RGB 555 but I need to manipulate it pixel per pixel, so I need to create an object from that constructor